# Ionic: Way to manually check ionViewDidLoad

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a function call that I'd like to execute during the `ionViewDidLoad()` lifecycle hook, but I need a value that is only present in the `ionViewDidEnter()` hook.

I can't call the function in the `ionViewDidEnter()` hook because it will overwrite a value each time the page loads which is undesired.

Is there any way to manually check if the page has loaded from cache within the `ionViewDidEnter()` hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
didEnter: boolean = false;

ionViewDidEnter() {
   if(this.didEnter) {
       console.log("This wasn't the first ionViewDidEnter");
   } else {
       this.didEnter = true;
       console.log("First ionViewDidEnter");
       // Do whatever you wanna do on only the first ionViewDidLoad
       // aka when it's not loaded from cache
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: simple, love it